# How can I connect to weblogic JMX via an SSH tunnel?

Tags: weblogic, jmx

I am trying to connect to weblogic via an SSH tunnel.

```
Local machine --> putty --> Linux server --> Anothe Linux server 2 with weblogic
```

I use the connect string t3:127.0.0.1:7001

When I connect to the web interface it works fine, but when I try to connect via JMX I get the message:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://127.0.0.1:7001: Bootstrap to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:7001 failed. It is likely that the remote side declared peer gone on this JVM]
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Details, please?  How are you connecting -- what is the exact ssh command line?  What are the hosts involved?

Comment: I use putty from my local windows machine to create an ssh tunnel on a remote Linux machine.

Comment: Is Weblogic configured to listen on that address, 127.0.0.1?

Comment: And how do you forward that tunnel from Linux 1 to Linux 2?